# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "App"

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Project with Node.js - Express  - MongoDB

when i am running app i am getting following error

```
E:\asista\asistabot2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:337
      throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
      ^
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "App".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at new MissingSchemaError (E:\asista\asistabot2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\missingSchema.js:20:11)
    at Mongoose.model (E:\asista\asistabot2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\inde    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\asista\asistabot2\app\controllers\chat.js:8:    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
```

This is part of my server.js

```
module.exports=app;
 // Bootstrap models
fs.readdirSync(models)
  .filter(file => ~file.search(/^[^\.].*\.js$/))
  .forEach(file => require(join(models, file)));

require('./config/express')(app);
require('./config/routes')(app);

connect()
  .on('error', console.log)
  .on('disconnected', connect)
  .once('open', listen);

function listen(){
    if(app.get('env')=='test')
     return;
    app.listen(port);
    console.log('Express app started on port ' + port);
}
function connect () {
    var dbUrl ='mongodb://localhost:27017/asista';
    mongoose.connect(dbUrl);
    var db=mongoose.connection;
    return db;
}
```

And this is part of my Chat.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const App =mongoose.model('App')
exports.chat =(req,res)=>{
     res.send('i am inside chat ->');
};
```

Database Model mentioned like this App.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var appSchema = new Schema({
    agent_key:String        

},{ collection: 'app' });

mongoose.model("app",appSchema);
```

What should I do? How do I fix it?

Comment: It means exactly what it says. [`mongoose.model(<ModelName>,<Schema>)`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-model) and you have not provided the `Schema`.

Comment: @NeilLunn updated model can you check it now

Comment: Did you read the duplicate about the order of execution? Does not sound like you did.

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining a Schema!

First you need to create a Schema like this

```
var appSchema = new Schema({
    name:  String
});
```

Then, you create a model from it

```
const App = mongoose.model('App', appSchema);
```

Or, you can provide the Schema to the model function

```
const App = mongoose.model('App', { name: String });
```